# Word 2007 VBA - Load macro on Document New via Addin

Tags: vba, ms-word

Good morning good folks! :) So here's what I'm trying to do. I've got this design template that I want to add to all new documents that are being created in Word 2007. In additon, I've got an addin in the form of a dotm file that's loaded everytime Word starts. This addin is located in the Startup folder on each computer. This is not a COM addin btw.

Now, I've tried a few things out. First of all, I've tried the `Document_New` and `Document_Open` handlers, as well as the `AutoExec` and `AutoOpen` handlers in the addin dotm-file. `Document_New` did not trigger anything when I start a new document. `Document_Open` didn't either. But `AutoExec` did trigger, but I can't apply the design profile in that trigger because there is no document open at that point.

So, how do I do this? I do not want to mess with the normal.dot at all, so I'm trying to avoid that and keep all code in the addin and perhaps a few macros in each template. But that's it. I want to keep it clean. Any ideas?

Comment: http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/AppClassEvents.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you hooking in to events at the Application level? or just at the document level? You need a "with events" reference to the Word application in order to trap the events you're interested in.

See here:  http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/AppClassEvents.htm

Comment: Ah thank you! This was exactly what I needed :) I thought the event Document_Open would trigger when the addin gets loaded via the startup folder. But it didn't. So this is great :)